# Rearranging bits inside an int to read/write multiple GPIOs

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, gpio

I have an ESP32 microcontroller where I need to directly write and read some GPIOs.
Basically, I need to move bits from a 4-bit value to some 4 positions in an uint32 output register. Also, the same in reverse, so read some other 4 positions in uint32 input register and pack them into a 4-bit value.

I would rather use any general optimizations, instead of anything that relies on particular pins or their order.

This is what I have now:

```
#define BIT(x) (1U << (x)) // from some builtin header

const gpio_num_t dig_in[4] = {GPIO_NUM_34, GPIO_NUM_35, GPIO_NUM_36, GPIO_NUM_39}; // same as {34, 35, 36, 39}
const gpio_num_t dig_out[4] = {GPIO_NUM_4, GPIO_NUM_25, GPIO_NUM_26, GPIO_NUM_27}; // same as { 4, 25, 26, 27}
```

Writing to pins:

```
void write_pins(uint8_t out)
{
    static const uint32_t masks[4] = {BIT(dig_out[0]), BIT(dig_out[1]), BIT(dig_out[2]), BIT(dig_out[3])};

    uint32_t set   = ((out & 0b0001) ? masks[0] : 0) | ((out & 0b0010) ? masks[1] : 0) | ((out & 0b0100) ? masks[2] : 0) | ((out & 0b1000) ? masks[3] : 0);
    uint32_t reset = (!(out & 0b0001) ? masks[0] : 0) | (!(out & 0b0010) ? masks[1] : 0) | (!(out & 0b0100) ? masks[2] : 0) | (!(out & 0b1000) ? masks[3] : 0);

    REG_WRITE(GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, set);
    REG_WRITE(GPIO_OUT_W1TC_REG, reset);
}
```

I found I can do that just with a tiny lookup table (or, rather, two) where the `out` is the index. Would that be any faster? Or maybe some other way? Reusing any of the intermediary values?

Reading from pins: (registers are 32 bit wide, and fortunately all my input pins are above GPIO32, so I can use only the upper register instead of both. For this reason all masks are shifted by 32. Not pretty, but idk how to do it better, without unnecessary performance hit of using 64 bit or array of 32 bits...)

```
uint8_t read_pins()
{
    static const uint32_t masks[4] = {BIT(dig_in[0] - 32), BIT(dig_in[1] - 32), BIT(dig_in[2] - 32), BIT(dig_in[3] - 32)};

    uint32_t pins = REG_READ(GPIO_IN1_REG);

    return (!!(pins & masks[0]) << 0) | (!!(pins & masks[1]) << 1) | (!!(pins & masks[2]) << 2) | (!!(pins & masks[3]) << 3);
}
```

A reverse lookup probably won't be any faster than direct bit operations. Is it possible to generate some magic constant (f.e. for multiplication or any other math op or even assembly) which would move the bits to required positions? I guess not in general case, but maybe with only 4 valid bits required out of 32? Any other suggestions to reduce number of instructions?

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the performance for this particular routine?  Your solution shouldn't be slow per se, but it looks plenty fast for any application I can think of.  If I'm reading this right, you could do `uint32_t reset = set ^ 0x0f;` in the write routine.  Also, in embedded, it is not uncommon to put things like this in order so you don't need to do this.  I know you said you don't want to rely on order or position, but if you are that worried about performance, that is *the* most efficient method.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no 4 pins in a row available anywhere. Either used internally or for other purposes (I2C, 2xSPI).
If anything, the `reset` would be a xor of `set` and mask of all positions, not `0xF`.
As for why I am concerned, this device will receive an arbitrary "routine" to perform, and I want simply to achieve a bitbanging as fast as possible, hopefully with a 1us loop.

Comment: Yeah.  I see now.  I don't think you can do much in the way of performance in this routine.  Maybe we could come up with something more elegant, but the compiler won't care about elegance and will emit similar instructions.  Is performance causing a problem here?

Comment: For `write_pins`, you could do a look-up table of the masks.  Since we are only talking about 4 bits, there are only 16 possibilities for `set` and `reset`.  So, you could pre-generate the masks.  I can't think of anything for `read_pins` though.  Using the same logic, you could mask off the bits you don't care about and do a `switch` on the 16 possible values.  That may or may not be faster.  You would need to do some measuring there.

Comment: There's a lot of conditional operators in the current approach. You can avoid that if you compute two arrays that represent right-shift and left-shift conversions to translate from your value bit to an out-pin bit, or from an in-pin bit to a value bit. You then loop through your table, mask and apply both shifts. This costs an extra table lookup but has less branching. Might be faster... ? Seems like micro-optimization here.

Comment: Actually, looking at what GCC outputs with `-O2` or `-O3` for your current `write_pins` function, it's pretty darn good. Is there really a problem here?

Comment: @Jason yeah, for `write` I found the lookup table solution somewhere on SO already, it will probably be the best.
Switch is an option, I would have to implement and compare. Though for that I would need to change the pins to constexpr, so that it has *any* chance to be compiled. And this all sits inside an object...

Comment: @paddy Can you provide some example? I don't think I understand.
I've never looked at assembly, especially for a uC. But it *is* compiled with GCC (though for Xtensa), so I guess it may be similar? I'm not much knowledgeable about such low level stuff.

Comment: @herhor67 Example assembly output for your functions: https://godbolt.org/z/cecMqMr8z -- as for Jason's suggestion of using a switch, a similar thing can be done for `read_pins` -- just pre-generate the 16 possible value pairs into an array and sort it. Now you can binary-search that array using a decision tree with exactly 4 comparisons.

Comment: Regarding the above example, the compiler is actually hard-coding your array values. This might not be relevant to your case, if you're providing these arrays as a generic user-configurable part of some library. Forcing the compiler to read that memory does actually result in a lot more instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/E3ojbaWEh

Comment: @paddy thanks for these, I will try some other possibilities. As for the example, I meant the `two arrays that represent right-shift and left-shift conversions [...]` because I don't quite get what you meant by that.

Comment: @herhor67 Oh right, I mean this: https://godbolt.org/z/T1355v6he -- it's just mapping each bit number to another bit number by computing the (positive) relative offsets to shift left and right (one of which will always be zero). Note the only branching is the loop, and with `-O3` the loop is unrolled so there is no branching. The execution time of the read and write routines is therefore predictable in a real-time system. Whether or not this is faster than your current solution would require careful testing. The other solution involving lookups with switch / binary search is probably better.

Comment: Hey, if this all sits in an object, you might be losing some opportunity for function inlining, depending on how translation units are organized.  There might be simpler gains possible on the outside of these functions if you want to provide some more code.  If the compiler is getting in your way, you can always use `#define` for much of these.

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I will probably change it to just a namespace. That was a pretty dumb design choice. I will try switch, check how it is compiled to assembly, and make everything that's possible a constexpr.